# Declare markup outside cc:implementation and let the cc:implementation include it

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, markup, composite-component

Well.
I created a custom component to CRUD and the form page is a parameter.
In this case I need two pages, one to define the component and another with the form.

Is there any way to do that?

As follow:

**Implementation:**

**Component**

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="formPage" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
    .....
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
...
    <h:form id="form-crud">
        <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.formPage}" />       
    </h:form>
...
</cc:implementation>
```

**Page 1: crud.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="content-template" >
    <comp:crud 
        paginaForm="crud-form.xhtml" />
</ui:define>
```

**Page 2: crud-form.xhtml**

```
<html ...
    <p:panelGrid id="grid-crud" columns="2" >
        <h:outputLabel for="dsName" value="Name: " />
        <p:inputText id="dsName"  value="#{crudBean.dsName}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>  
</html>
```

**New Implementation (sample)**

To simplify, I would like to have component defnition and form in the same page, something like that. Is it possible?
I know I could use a template, but the custom componet has more attributes.

**New Component**

```
<cc:implementation>
...
    <h:form id="form-crud">
        <XX:SOMETING name="#{cc.attrs.formContent}" />      
    </h:form>
...
</cc:implementation>
```

**New Page 1: new-crud.xhtml**

```
...
<ui:define name="content-template" >
    <comp:crud 
        form="new-form" />

    <XX:SOMETING id="new-form">

        <p:panelGrid id="grid-crud" columns="2" >
            <h:outputLabel for="dsName" value="Name: " />
            <p:inputText id="dsName"  value="#{crudBean.dsName}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>  

    </XX:SOMETING>

</ui:define>
...
```

Comment: This is the second time I fixed a terminology error in your question. Those are not custom components. Those are composite components. To learn the difference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Comment: ok @BalusC, tip received! I'll pay attention on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`<f:facet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/facet.html) exactly like as those work with e.g. `<h:dataTable>`/`<h:column>` header/footer.

First declare a [`<cc:facet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/cc/facet.html) with the desired name:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:facet name="form" />
</cc:interface>
```

Then declare a [`<cc:renderFacet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/cc/renderFacet.html) in the desired place where it should end up:

```
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <h:form>
        <cc:renderFacet name="form" />
    </h:form>
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```html
<comp:crud>
    <f:facet name="form">
        ...
    </f:facet>
</comp:crud>
```

Please note that this construct is also possible with "plain vanilla" Facelets tagfiles via `<ui:define>`/`<ui:insert>` mechanisms.